# HTML/Body height to 100% for horizontal scrollbar control breaking .animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In Chrome (maybe others), I'm getting a conflict between setting the horizontal scrollbar to be at the bottom of the window with `html, body { height: 100%; }` and jQuery .animate() scrolling. When the "Scroll to #target" button is clicked, the page scrolls to the wrong spot. Have tried setting `html, body { min-height: 100% }` which fixes the scrolling, but then this drops the horizontal scrollbar to below the bottom of the window. Please advise.

Markup is:

```js
        jQuery('button#scroll').click((e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            jQuery('html, body').animate(
                { scrollTop: jQuery(`#target`).offset().top - 100 },
                200,
            );
        });
```

```css
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
  /* height: auto; */
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wide-div {
  background: orange;
  height: 50px;
  width: 10000px;
}

.spacer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="scroll">Scroll to #target</button>
    <div class="wide-div"></div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div id="target">Here's the target</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you posted is working for me. Can you try your code in incognito (in case an extension may be causing this)?

Comment: @Saddy just adjusted styling